# Export Groups with members and permissions import to new server adding groups with members and same permissions

Tags: powershell

I'm in need of some PowerShell help. I have two options:

**Option 1:** Export groups (which are local) with member groups and permissions and then import groups to new server with member groups and same permissions.

**Option 2:** Export member groups and add directly to the share, because these are domain groups when we do the migration the permissions should be carried across.

I've been using the code from [this tutorial](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/11/get-all-members-of-a-local-group-using-powershell/), which provides some of the information.

I use this function to extract the groups and its members *(sorry about the confusion with the permissions, that is done on the share\folder)* :

```
Function Get-LocalGroup {

    [Cmdletbinding()]

    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [String[]]$Computername = $Env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [parameter()]
        [string[]]$Group
    )

    Begin {
        Function ConvertTo-SID {
            Param([byte[]]$BinarySID)
            (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($BinarySID,0)).Value
        }

        Function Get-LocalGroupMember {
            Param ($Group)
            $group.Invoke('members') | ForEach {
                $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
            }
        }
    }

    Process {
        ForEach ($Computer in $Computername) {
            Try {
                Write-Verbose "Connecting to $($Computer)"
                $adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer"

                If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Group')) {
                    Write-Verbose "Scanning for groups: $($Group -join ',')"
                    $Groups  = ForEach  ($item in  $group) {                        
                        $adsi.Children.Find($Item, 'Group')
                    }
                } Else {
                    Write-Verbose  "Scanning all groups"
                    $groups = $adsi.Children | Where-Object { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'group' }
                }

                If ($groups) {
                    $groups | ForEach {
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            Computername = $Computer
                            Name = $_.Name[0]
                            Members = ((Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $_)) -join ', '
                            SID = (ConvertTo-SID -BinarySID $_.ObjectSID[0])
                        }
                    }
                } Else {
                    Throw "No groups found!"
                }
            } Catch {
                Write-Warning "$($Computer): $_"
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-LocalGroup -Computername $env:COMPUTERNAME -Group Administrators, Users -Verbose | Format-List
```

And once I have the members I need a way of adding them to the same share, so basically we can remove the local groups.

We have local groups on a 2003 server which have nested in them domain security groups, what I want to do is get the members (which are groups) out of the local groups and add them directly to the share and then delete the local groups, this shouldn't affect any users and once this is done we can migrate the shares retaining the permissions.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please share the code you have written so far (you can edit your question to add it) ? Also, what permissions are you talking about ? Usually, permissions are set on resources, not groups.